# Why is the set of natural numbers not considered a non-Abelian group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I don't understand why the set of natural numbers constitutes a commutative monoid with addition, but is not considered an Abelian group.

Comment: What is the additive inverse of $n\neq 0$?

Comment: It's not a nonabelian group. It's an abelian nongroup.

Comment: Note that $\mathbb N$ is not considered a group (even less an abelian group), but your question title suggests that it is considered a non-abelian group - no it isn't even a non-abelian group.

Comment: Such a "great" question deserves more than 3 upvotes!

Answer (score 19):

*Addition on the natural numbers* ***IS commutative*** ...

...but the natural numbers under addition do ***not*** form a group.

**Why not a group?**

- if you define $\mathbb{N} = \{ n\in \mathbb{Z} \mid n\ge 1\}$, as we typically do, then it *fails to be a group* because it does not contain $0$, the additive *identity*. 
  Indeed, $\mathbb{N} = \{ n\in \mathbb{Z} \mid n\ge 1\}$ fails to be a monoid, if the additive identity $0\notin \mathbb{N}$. 
  So I will assume you are defining $\mathbb{N} = \mathbb{Z}^{+} = \{x \in \mathbb{Z} \mid x \ge 0\}$, which is indeed a commutative monoid: addition is both associative and commutative on $\mathbb{N}$, and $0 \in \mathbb{N}$ if $\mathbb{N} = \mathbb{Z}^{+} = \{x \in \mathbb{Z} \mid x \ge 0\}$.
- There is no additive inverse for any $n\in \mathbb{N}, n \ge 1$. For example, there is no element $x \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $3 + x = 0.$ Hence the natural numbers  *cannot be* a *GROUP*.

A *monoid* is a *group* if it also (in addition to being associative, has the additive identity for addition) satisfies the ADDED requirement that the *inverse* element of each element in the monoid is also in the monoid. (In such case, the monoid is said to be a group.)

Comment: n_ary_crazy: Are you familiar with the  properties of a "group" - as that term is used in math?

Comment: If OP states that $\Bbb N$ is a commutative monoid, then you may infer that she considers $0\in\Bbb N$.

Answer (score 7):

The natural numbers do not have inverses, hence they are not a group.

Answer (score 6):

What is a *monoid*?

> A monoid is an algebraic structure with a single associative binary operation and an identity element.

Formally, a monoid is a set, $S$, with a binary operation, $\cdot$, that satisfies the following three axioms:
$$a\cdot b \in S \quad \forall a,b \in S.$$
$$(a \cdot b)\cdot c=a\cdot (b\cdot c) \quad \forall a,b,c \in S.$$
$$\exists e \in S: e\cdot a=a\cdot e=a \quad \forall a \in S.$$
These axioms are, in other words, *closure*, *associativity*, and *the existence of an identity*. (Some would formally say the existence of a left and right identity which are equivalent.)

Depending on your definition of $\mathbb{N}$, we may or may not have a monoid. If $\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,2,\cdots\}$, then we have a monoid $(\mathbb{N},+)$ since all three aforementioned axioms are satisfied. (In particular, we have $e=0$.)

Now, here's where I think your confusion lies: You don't know particularly what a *group* is. In fact, a group is a special kind of monoid! It is a monoid with the additional axiom below:
$$\exists a^{-1}: a\cdot a^{-1}=a^{-1}\cdot a=e \quad \forall a\in S.$$
Thus, we see a group is a monoid with the addition of inverses. Since there are not inverses in $(\mathbb{N}, +)$, $(\mathbb{N},+)$ is not a group. There are not inverses for a clear reason: What do we add to $1$ to return $0$, for example? $-1$. That's not in $\mathbb{N}$, hence we have at least one example where there is not an inverse and that's enough to state $(\mathbb{N},+)$ is not a group.

What should be noted is the following awesomeness: $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ is a monoid and a group, and not just any group: An *abelian* group. ;-D

---

What you'll find throughout mathematics is the following awesomeness: There are generalizations between generalizations between generalizations between . . . ad infinitum (?). We're seeing this here. The algebraic structure of a group is a generalization of what we see in $(\mathbb{Z},+)$. Similarly, a monoid is an even weaker 'version' of a group. (This is informal.) On top of this, we have the notion of a *semigroup*: A generalization of a monoid by removing the necessity for an identity element. So, if we define $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,\dots\}$, we have that $(\mathbb{N},+)$ is a *semigroup*, and not a monoid nor group.

What's awesome is the rabbit hole goes further: There is a structure known as a *magma* (some call it a *groupoid*, but this often causes confusion with a category theory groupoid). This is a semigroup without the axiom of associativity. That means that the only axiom it imposes on the operation and set is closure. Cool stuff, right?

In summary,

$$\dots \subset \text{Magma} \subset \text{Semigroup} \subset \text{Monoid} \subset \text{Group} \subset \text{Abelian Group} \subset \cdots$$

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the axiom of choice one can actually endow any set with a group structure.

To get a group structure for $\mathbb N$ define for example $f: \mathbb Z \to \mathbb N$, $k \mapsto 2|k|$ if $k \leq 0$ and $k \mapsto 2k + 1$ otherwise. Now define addition on $\mathbb N$ as follows: let $n + m := f^{-1}(n) + f^{-1}(m)$.

Verify that $f$ is a (group) isomorphism, that $0$ is the additive identity and that the additive inverse of $n$ is $f(-f^{-1}(n))$.